# Mysql my.cnf file prevents server startup

Tags: mysql

Something in my.cnf file is preventing mysql (5.7.20) from starting up/shutting down and I don't know which entry or entries are the problem. I am getting a can't connect to localhost 61/2003 error. The my.cnf file is:

```
[mysqld]
general-log=1
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql_general.log
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql_slow.log
long_query_time = 10
log-error = /var/log/mysql_error.log
#port=3306
#socket=tmp/mysql.sock
#skip-external-locking
innodb_page_cleaners = 2
optimizer_switch = derived_merge=off
optimizer_search_depth = 0
slow-query-log=1
#pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
character-set-client-handshake = false #force encode to utf8
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[client]
#port=3306
#socket=tmp/mysql.sock
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

I know I can comment out everything and uncomment 1 by 1 until it fails, but renaming the file to my.cnf.old constantly so server can start is time consuming. I would wonder if anyone spots an error off the bat.

Permissions on the file are 644 root wheel (-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel). Are those are the correct permissions and ownership?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Check the error log for your MySQL Server, and search for "ERROR" to find the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There were several problems found. Ownership of the log files needed to be mysql, not root. And the my.cnf needed to have port=3306 in both the [mysqld] and [client] sections. Once these were fixed, server startup and shutdown worked fine.